# Extremely slow raw SQL queries on web2py

Tags: python, mysql, performance, web2py

*db.executesql()* takes 30 seconds to return a result, despite the fact that same query takes 0.5-1 second if I try it on the MySQL console or with the same code on the web2py debug console or on the web2py shell.

```
dbs._timings #From the first test below
  [('SELECT 1;', 0.016000032424926758), #web2py or driver stuff, I didn't execute it.
   ('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;', 0.003999948501586914), #web2py or driver stuff, I didn't execute it.
   ("SET sql_mode='NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';", 0.00800013542175293), #web2py or driver stuff, I didn't execute it.
   ("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(...) AS 'duration',\n
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(...)\n
                    - INTERVAL 1 HOUR, TIMESTAMP(...)\n
                    + INTERVAL CAST(...) AS 'timediff',\n
             ris.ODATE as 'date',\n
             CONCAT(...) as 'service'\n
        FROM ... AS ris\n
        JOIN ... as sd on ris.... = sd....\n
        WHERE ris.... != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'\n
              and ris.... != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'\n
              and ris.... >= '2010-8-15'\n
              and ris.... <= '2014-8-22'", 32.0460000038147), # Slow query/code, executed on page view.
     ("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(...) AS 'duration',\n
             TIMESTAMPDIFF(...)\n
                    - INTERVAL 1 HOUR, TIMESTAMP(...)\n
                    + INTERVAL CAST(...) AS 'timediff',\n
             ris.ODATE as 'date',\n
             CONCAT(...) as 'service'\n
        FROM ... AS ris\n
        JOIN ... as sd on ris.... = sd....\n
        WHERE ris.... != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'\n
              and ris.... != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'\n
              and ris.... >= '2010-8-15'\n
              and ris.... <= '2014-8-22'", 0.6069998741149902) #Same query/code, exec. on the debug console]
```

I tried the following cases:

```
... #Irrelevant part of the code
raw_data = dbs.executesql(query, as_dict=True) #Takes 30 seconds to return a result
from gluon.debug import dbg
dbg.set_trace() #After this line, I'm on the debug console
raw_data = dbs.executesql(query, as_dict=True) #Takes <1 second to return a result
dbs._timings #print
```

and

```
... #Irrelevant part of the code
from gluon.debug import dbg
dbg.set_trace() #After this line, I'm on the debug console
raw_data = dbs.executesql(query, as_dict=True) #Takes <1 second to return a result
```

Things got interesting when I try to execute more queries consecutively:

```
... #Irrelevant part of the code
raw_data = dbs.executesql(query, as_dict=True) #Takes 7 seconds to return a result
raw_data = dbs.executesql(query, as_dict=True) #Takes 7 seconds to return a result
raw_data = dbs.executesql(query, as_dict=True) #Takes 7 seconds to return a result
from gluon.debug import dbg
dbg.set_trace() #After this line, I'm on the debug console
raw_data = dbs.executesql(query, as_dict=True) #Takes <1 second to return a result
```

on HeidiSQL

```
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 7,391  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.000 sec. (+ 0.078 sec. network) */
```

Comment: If you run the debug right after the first query it will not be useful because it may use the internal mysql cache. Try installing phpmyadmin or something the allows you to easily run profile or explain of the query. There you'll find what type of operations it is really doing and you can share it with us for a better understanding of the bottleneck.